# how to capture the child process termination when the parent process is waiting the signal from child process

Tags: multiprocessing, signals

now my parent process is suspended to wait the siguser1 from child process like this

```
sigset_t mask;
sigfillset(&mask);
sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
sigsuspend(&mask);
```

so my parent has been blocked.
but sometimes the child process will not send the siguser1 to the parent process but terminate first. So how can the parent process know the child process terminate already and not to wait the signal and do the next process.
what's more, i find that wait is also not working because it will block the parent process.

Comment: i don't think pause is working because it also wait for the signal.

Comment: One of my guiding principles of multiprocessing is "never wait forever". Set a timer with a reasonable interval, and poll the state of the process maybe? It's not fancy, but it is reliable.